# Trim the first 11 seconds from an mp3 file

Tags: shell, split, mp3

I'm trying to write a script that takes off the first 11 seconds from more than 100 mp3 files.

Can I use the "split" command to do it? Or is there any Mac CLI program that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp3 -ss 11 outfile.mp3
```

In case your ffmpeg does not support mp3 encoding, try below:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp3 -ss 11 /tmp/outfile.wav
lame /tmp/outfile.wav outfile.mp3
```

You will need to install these packages though :)

Comment: it supports mp3, but this outputs the first 11 seconds instead..

Comment: actually -ss option removes the 11 first seconds! cheers

Comment: Oh I interpreted your question wrongly... I thought you want to keep initial 11 seconds, removing rest... Updating answer :-)